# IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains a few rows. I want to access one by one row and create another data frame with specific columns. After that running some other logics but it failed before that.

**Dataframe df_input_data**

```
src_table_name src_column_name src_business_key_name  
0  banking_fraud         Acct_id               Acct_id   
1      sale_mast       cust_code               bill_no
```

**Access row using iterrows():**

```
for index, df_input_single in df_input_data.iterrows():
print("input", df_input_single)
```

**Output:**

```
input src_table_name                                      banking_fraud
src_column_name                                           Acct_id
src_business_key_name                                     Acct_id
```

Creating another dataframe:

```
df_src_input = pd.DataFrame().assign(table_name=df_input_single['src_table_name'],
                                     column_name=df_input_single['src_column_name'],
                                     business_key_name=df_input_single['src_business_key_name'])
```

issue is `df_src_input` is empty.

```
df_src_input Empty DataFrame
Columns: [table_name, column_name, business_key_name, select_column_names, where_condition, end_date, load_dt_tm, src_tgt_validation_type, schema_name, schema_table]
Index: []
```

Is there any other way to assign value to different dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you print out

```
print('type', type(df_input_single['src_column_name']))
```

for example, it will be type `<class 'str'>`, which is just a string value. To put data in a column, it must be a `list` or a `tuple`. Put each value in square brackets.

```
for index, df_input_single in df_input_data.iterrows():
    #print('input', df_input_single)
    #print('type', type(df_input_single['src_column_name']))
    df_src_input = pd.DataFrame().assign(table_name=[df_input_single['src_table_name']],
                                         column_name=[df_input_single['src_column_name']],
                                         business_key_name=[df_input_single['src_business_key_name']])

    print(df_src_input)
```